# combining multiple columns in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Here is my tables:

### T1 record:

```
id  referencePerson1ID  referencePerson2ID  referencePerson3ID 

1         1                    2                  3
```

T2 referencePerson:

```
id                     name

1                      Peter
2                      John
3                      Mary
```

I want to get the following result when I choose `T1 id =1`:

```
id  referencePerson1  referencePerson2  referencePerson3

1       Peter              John             Mary
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with three times JOIN :

```
SELECT t1.id, t21.name, t22.name, t23.name
FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN T2 t21 ON t21.id = T1.referencePerson1ID
    INNER JOIN T2 t22 ON t22.id = T1.referencePerson2ID
    INNER JOIN T2 t23 ON t23.id = T1.referencePerson3ID
WHERE T1.id = 1
```

Comment: Note that if any of the referencePersonNID columns contains a NULL or a value that does not have a matching om the referencePerson table, this query would not return that row. (It's possible that's the desired behavior. It's possible there's NOT NULL and (enforced) FOREIGN KEY constraints on all three of the columns too.)

Comment: yep I'm aware of that so it's 50-50 decision to me when writing the answer. Anyway, your comment make it clearer for OP to decide whether to go with INNER JOIN, or LEFT JOIN :)

Comment: This query it neat and clean. But there is an issue @har07, the user wanted `referencePerson1       referencePerson2       referencePerson3 ` where as this query returns columns as 'name name name`. Anyways users accept meant he might got the way. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is one basic way to do things:

```
SELECT T1.id, P1.name, P2.name, p3.name 
FROM  record T1 LEFT JOIN referencePerson P1 
ON T1.referencePerson1ID=P1.id
LEFT JOIN referencePerson P2 
ON T1.referencePerson2ID=P2.id
LEFT JOIN referencePerson P3
ON T1.referencePerson3ID=P3.id
```

Another way when number of persons is unknown can be done using a PIVOT